# Synthetic Data Vault doesn´t generate data (takes extreme long time)

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, sample-data, sdv

I am new into ML and not really familiar with python. I want to extend a csv file using this script below. But it takes an extreme long time (even after half an hour) to generate 5000 rows of sample data. I cant find my failure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh7QY.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.